# Why does measuring one qubit after the other in this entangled system alter the result?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, measurement

Suppose I have the following circuit where q0 and q1 are measured one after the other.

[image: Circuit diagram]

The simulation results state that the state 00 occurs 75% of the time, and the state 11 occurs 25% of the time. But if you measure both at the same time, you get 00 and 11 50% of the time each.

Here are my calculations:

$\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
           \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
         \end{bmatrix} \otimes 
\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
         \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
           0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
0
         \end{bmatrix}$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
           1, 0, 0, 0 \\
0, 1, 0, 0 \\
0, 0, 0, 1 \\
0, 0, 1, 0 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
           0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
0
         \end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
           0 \\
0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
         \end{bmatrix}
$

We now have an entangled state. First H gate:

$(H \otimes I) \begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
           0 \\
0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
         \end{bmatrix} = $
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2}
         \end{bmatrix}$

2nd H gate:

$(H \otimes I)
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2}
         \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
0 \\
0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
         \end{bmatrix}$

Thus there should be a 50-50 chance of the final state either being 00 or 11, but how come measuring the results one after the other changes it?

Comment: The last 2 H gates in the circuit don't really do anything; I was testing a program I was making and they happened to be there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the simulator is saying that state 00 occurs 75% of the time then the simulator has a bug. Reordering measurements can't make certain outcomes more likely in that way. It would violate the no communication theorem.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just some notes:

1) A symbol for tensor product is $\otimes$, so I edited your answer so.

2) After CNOT, you do not have to calculate firstly tensor product $H \otimes I$ and then $I \otimes H$ (by the way, you calculated $H \otimes I$ instead of $I \otimes H$ in step you denoted 2nd H) and simply use $H \otimes H$

3) Regarding your comment "two Hadamards gate do nothing". They in fact change basis you measure in from z-basis to x-basis. However, if you measure your state proudced by Hadamard and CNOT (this is called Bell $\beta_{00}$ state) in both bases then you get same results. But please bear in mind that in case of another measured states, the result with and without $H$s could be different.